# What is this piece of code doing? :(){:|:&};:

Tags: bash

Sorry for asking such a general question but this has been bugging me for days.

A friend gave me this piece of code (?) and wont tell me what it does, or even if it is C or bash or anything else.

From the look of it, it looks like C to me. Although I dont get why there are `:` on the sides.

```
:(){:|:&};:
```

Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Nonsense! Just make sure that when you try "random" code from an untrusted source that you run it inside a non-networked VM. :)

Comment: That's not a friend I would take more code from... if he tells you to do `chmod -R 666 /`, I wouldn't do that either

Comment: I didn't run it of course. The only thing fork bombed here was my mind =)

Comment: This is a syntax error in bash.  It might run in zsh, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is bash shell script, not C.

It's a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Wikipedia explains it:

```
:()      # define ':' -- whenever we say ':', do this:
{        # beginning of what to do when we say ':'
    :    # load another copy of the ':' function into memory...
    |    # ...and pipe its output to...
    :    # ...another copy of ':' function, which has to be loaded into memory
         # (therefore, ':|:' simply gets two copies of ':' loaded whenever ':' is called)
    &    # disown the functions -- if the first ':' is killed,
         #     all of the functions that it has started should NOT be auto-killed
}        # end of what to do when we say ':'
;        # Having defined ':', we should now...
:        # ...call ':', initiating a chain-reaction: each ':' will start two more.
```

Comment: I usually recommend "Try it and see" but not on this one.

Comment: The key is knowing that the ':' symbol is the command name.  If you replace it with a more normal-looking variable name it is easier to spot: foo(){foo|foo&};foo  The trick is that your brain sees : as just another special character.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fork bomb and I would not run that on your system. It will cause a bunch of processes to spawn and ultimately slow down or crash your system.